# Log4j2 environment variable lookup mechanism does not work with "type" attribute

Tags: xml, layout, log4j, log4j2

I need to configure a Log4j2 Appender Layout using a variable provided at application startup. Basically, according to the specific running environment I need to use either a layout or another.

Currently I use an XML configuration with the following setup.

- I defined an env variable named **LAYOUT** having the layout type as value (e.g.: `CustomLayout`);
- In `log4j2.xml` file I defined the following appender:

```
    <Appender type="Console" name="ConsoleAppender">
        <PatternLayout type="${env:LAYOUT}" />
    </Appender>
```

However, whenever I start my application, I get the following message:

```
ERROR Console contains an invalid element or attribute "${env:LAYOUT}".
```

Alas, in other sections of the same XML, the `${env:}` lookup mechanism works properly, for example here:

```
    <Root level="${env:ROOT_LOG_LEVEL:-DEBUG}">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </Root>
```

It seems to me that the property lookup mechanism of Log4j does not work with the `type` attribute. What am I doing wrong? Is this because `type` attribute has a different resolution time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it seems that the property lookup mechanism of Log4j does not work with the `type` attribute, I managed my need with this workaround:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="AdvancedConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <AdvancedLayout/>
    </Console>
    <Console name="CustomConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <CustomLayout/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="${env:ROOT_LOG_LEVEL:-DEBUG}">
        <AppenderRef ref="${env:LOG_APPENDER:-CustomConsoleAppender}" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

basically the approach is the following:

- I define two appenders, each containing a different layout type;
- In the `<AppenderRef>` of my `<Root>` level I use an environment variable referring to the name of the appender I need to use in the specific runtime environment.

Because of this workaround now I am able to use different layouts and log levels in different environments.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

1. You specified `${env:LAYOUT}`. When a lookup resolves to null then the string value of the lookup is the string itself - i.e. `${env:LAYOUT}`. This means that the value of LAYOUT was not found as an OS environment variable. When you configured the level on your root Logger you specified `${env:ROOT_LOG_LEVEL:-DEBUG}`, which means if ROOT_LOG_LEVEL is not found as an environment variable then the value to be used should be "DEBUG". If you want your application to run when an environment variable is not defined then you must provide a default value.
2. You specified an attribute named "type" on the PatternLayout. The type attribute can only be used when `strict-true` is specified on the configuration element. But when that is the case your configuration would need to look like:

```
    <Appender type="Console" name="ConsoleAppender">
        <Layout type="${env:LAYOUT}" />
    </Appender>
```

Note that in order for this configuration to work each of the Layouts you might specify with the type attribute must accept exactly the same configuration elements.

Comment: Hi @rgoers, thank you for the answer. Actually I tried also with strict=true configuration and with a:

<Layout type="${env:LAYOUT:-DefaultLayout}" />

but I get the same error. :(